# Jsoup div[class=] syntax works whereas div.class syntax doesn't - Why?

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup

For the following HTML snippet:

```
<div class="class_one class_two class_three classfour classfive classsix">
some inner content
</div>
```

The following Jsoup selector **works**:

```
div[class=class_one class_two class_three classfour classfive classsix]
```

But the equivalent div.class syntax **doesn't** work:

```
div.class_one.class_two.class_three.classfour.classfive.classsix
```

Why? What am I missing?

**EDIT**: Based on the feedback I received below, I realize that I failed to explain what "doesn't work" means. This was due to my confusion as to how multiclass selection syntax works. By "not working" I meant that the `.classname` syntax above selects way too many divs than the `class=classname` syntax (with the same exact number of classname and in the same order!) does, because the HTML in question contained additional divs with a 7th class name... It turns out that this is [by design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7563421/multiclass-element-selection-clarification/7563453#7563453). That's what I was missing, and thanks to @Hovercraft Full Of Eels and @BalusC who helped me discover this.

Comment: That should work. Can you try it with maybe just two classes?

Comment: Do you have a public web page that you're trying to analyze and can provide a link here? Can you also provide a small compilable and runnable program (an [sscce](http://sscce.org)) that demonstrates your problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Again, as per my comment, you need to show us your code in context to show how it isn't working.

For instance when I try to analyze this simple text:

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <div class="class_one class_two class_three classfour classfive classsix">
    some inner content 
  </div> 
 </body>
</html>
```

With this code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class Foo {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(Foo.class.getResourceAsStream("Foo.txt"));
      String text = "";
      while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
         text += scan.nextLine() + "\n";
      }
      Document doc = Jsoup.parse(text);

      Elements eles = doc.select("div.class_one.class_two.class_three.classfour.classfive.classsix");
      System.out.println(eles);
   }
}
```

I get this result:

```
<div class="class_one class_two class_three classfour classfive classsix">
  some inner content 
</div>
```

Suggesting that your use of select *should* work, and if it's not working, something else may be going on. Your best bet may be to do what I've just done: post some data and some compilable runnable code (an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)) and have it show just how your code is not working.

Comment: Hint: Jsoup has also a `parse()` method taking an `InputStream`. You could use it as follows: `Jsoup.parse(Foo.class.getResourceAsStream("Foo.txt"), "UTF-8", null);`

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels Thanks +1 and sorry for the late feedback. See EDIT in my OP.