# Multiclass element selection clarification

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup

Assuming several multiclass divs as demonstrated in the following HTML:

```
<div class="class_one class_two class_three classfour classfive classsix">

<div class="class_one class_two class_three classfour classfive">

<div class="class_one class_two class_three classfour classsix">
```

Is there a single Jsoup select expression that will select all 3 of them?

To clarify, thinking that the "lowest common denominator" will select all 3, I tried the following:

```
div[class=class_one class_two class_three classfour]
```

But it selected **none**!

On the other hand, using the full multiselect syntax works, but it can only select one of the above, e.g.:

```
div[class=class_one class_two class_three classfour classfive classsix]
```

Is there a way to select all 3 of them, using a *single* Jsoup select statement?

Comment: Shouldn't you first reply to my [answer to your previous recent question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7560083/jsoup-divclass-syntax-works-whereas-div-class-syntax-doesnt-why/7562003#7562003) before posting a new one? Why answer this question if you will ignore it like the previous?  And where is your [sscce](http://sscce.org)?

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels Thanks for your reply and questions. Your answer to previous recent question helped me find a bug in my code. Now I am trying to understand how Jsoup works in this regard, so that I can update the previous question accordingly (or delete it). If you notice, the above quetion is not at all the same as the previous question. In fact, it's almost opposite.

Comment: His answer didn't got any feedback and you didn't edit the question to provide more context about the concrete problem. To me, at first sight, the both questions boil down to the same issue and the above should actually be edited into your previous recent question.

Comment: @BalusC You're right the previous question, but this question is not about context or concrete problem. It's really a question about understanding a Jsoup feature which for some reason is not documented. I could of course come up with numerous SSCCEs to discover how it works emperically, but that if Jsoup behaves in a way that's *not* per its indended design, I will never know this. Really, all I am asking is whether this particular Jsoup multiclass select is an "or" or "and" operation.

Comment: Okay then, but please provide feedback to Hovercraft's answer on your previous recent question.

Comment: @BalusC Of course I will provide feedback. I am in the process of testing his excellent answer and providing the most accurate and authoritative feedback (at least as I experience it. I am still using Jsoup 1.5.2 and I haven't had the time to upgrade to 1.6.1 yet).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not specific to Jsoup, but to CSS. The `[attribute=name]` selector does an **exact match**. Even the ordering matters. You want to use the `.classname` selector here instead. The following should work:

```
Elements divs = document.select("div.class_one.class_two.class_three.classfour");
// ...
```

Note that ordering of the classnames doesn't matter here. This selector selects all `<div>` elements which has all of the given classnames present.

#### See also:

- [Jsoup selector syntax](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax)
- [Jsoup `Selector` API javadoc](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html)

Comment: OMG You have just revealed to me a misconception I had up until now: I always thought that `[class=name]` and `.classname` are 100% equivalent in Jsoup. Now I see that they are slightly different in at least the **exact match** aspect. Thanks so much!